# SQL Server 2012 - Sales Summary with best day marker

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do a sales report which I have done, but the boss wants a marker against the day in the week that is the busiest!

My tables are

**Tills**

```
TillID  BranchID    TillNo  OperatorID
1       1           1       1
2       1           2       2
3       1           3       3
4       2           1       4
5       3           1       5
```

**Sales**:

```
TillID  SaleTS              Net
1       01/01/2016 09:00    9
1       01/01/2016 10:00    76
2       01/01/2016 09:00    35
2       01/01/2016 10:00    84
3       01/01/2016 09:00    68
3       01/01/2016 10:00    43
4       01/01/2016 09:00    12
4       01/01/2016 10:00    0
5       01/01/2016 09:00    79
5       01/01/2016 10:00    25
1       02/01/2016 09:00    90
1       02/01/2016 10:00    16
2       02/01/2016 09:00    58
2       02/01/2016 10:00    96
3       02/01/2016 09:00    36
3       02/01/2016 10:00    25
4       02/01/2016 09:00    85
4       02/01/2016 10:00    74
5       02/01/2016 09:00    14
5       02/01/2016 10:00    12
1       03/01/2016 09:00    45
1       03/01/2016 10:00    78
2       03/01/2016 09:00    98
2       03/01/2016 10:00    65
3       03/01/2016 09:00    32
3       03/01/2016 10:00    19
4       03/01/2016 09:00    37
4       03/01/2016 10:00    79
5       03/01/2016 09:00    46
5       03/01/2016 10:00    13
```

**Results**:

```
TillID  SaleDate    Day         DailyNet    BestDay
1       01/01/2016  Friday      85          No
1       02/01/2016  Saturday    106         No
1       03/01/2016  Sunday      123         Yes
2       01/01/2016  Friday      119         No
2       02/01/2016  Saturday    154         No
2       03/01/2016  Sunday      163         Yes
3       01/01/2016  Friday      111         Yes
3       02/01/2016  Saturday    61          No
3       03/01/2016  Sunday      51          No
4       01/01/2016  Friday      12          No
4       02/01/2016  Saturday    159         Yes
4       03/01/2016  Sunday      116         No
5       01/01/2016  Friday      104         Yes
5       02/01/2016  Saturday    26          No
5       03/01/2016  Sunday      59          No
```

My query is doing everything but the total, I can do this by building a derived table of just the max per day but this is going to get slow over time linking these tables.

I have been looking and can not find another way to get this marker.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want totals make use of ROLLUP clause:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

BestDay can be produced like this:

```
case when DailyNet = max(DailyNet) over(partition by TillID) then 'Yes' else 'No'
```

Comment: Sorry just noticed i had put i could not get the total when i meant the bestday columns, i have edited the question now.

Comment: Pioty thank you for you update. I have managed to get this to work although i need to get it to sum over the working week. This worked by adding the week number and year to the partition. The problem i have is that this does not count the first few days of the year as the same week as the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the till table, I'm guessing you are a retail company so your week numbers won't correspond to calendar week numbers as generally you want weeks that go from either Sunday to Saturday or Monday To Sunday.
Ideally, you'd use your systems calendar to identify weeks and months.
But as a simple trick, you can simply assign the week based on the appropriate offset.
For example, this year the first sunday is 1/3.  so, it needs to act like 1/1 or 2 days later.

```
 @WEEK = DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,-2,@CurrentDate))
```

This would only work for this year.   Ideally, you'd create a date table which has the appropriately calculated week for all years (which I'll if I have time)